# htaccess убираем php ошибка одинаковых имен папок и файлов

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, как все знают чтобы убрать у названия файла его расширение надо в htaccess ввести следующее

```
# Запускаем движок замены
RewriteEngine on
 # Если запрашиваемый объект не папка
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 # если запрашиваемый объект с дописанным расширением php - файл
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 # делаем замену с дописыванием .php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Я столкнулся со следующей проблемой, все работает отлично если не одно но, если у вас на одном уровне имеется файл например ru.php и папка ru то при обращении например к файлу site.com/ru  меня переводит не на ru.php а на автомате перекидывает в папку site.com/ru/

Кто знает как решить этот вопрос?

По скрипту:
(переименовать папку или файл это не решение вопроса, а уход от проблемы которую хотелось бы решить).

Comment: Ну так уберите `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Comment: Апач сначала дописывает слеш в конце при наличии папки, а только потом обрабатывает правила редиректа. Так что тупик.

Comment: Убрал  не помогло, неужто придется менять веб сервер чтоб такое провернуть.

Comment: А nginx думаете по другому папки обрабатывает?

Comment: @Visman Интересная информация. Опыт или это в документации написано? Может это решиться с помощью `DirectorySlash off`?

Comment: @tutankhamun, где-то на просторах интернета встречал, а где точно сейчас уже не помню.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверил информацию, полученную от @Visman. Действительно Apache дописывает слеш если есть директория, но тут дело в модуле `mod_dir` и директиве `DirectorySlash`. По-умолчанию значение директивы `on` и Apache возвращает ответ 301 с URL который оканчивается на слеш.

Решение вашей проблемы такое:

```
# запускаем движок замены
RewriteEngine on
# если запрашиваемый объект с дописанным расширением php - файл
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
# делаем замену с дописыванием .php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
# отключаем редирект для директорий без слеша
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectorySlash off
</IfModule>
```

См. также

- [Описание директивы DirectorySlash](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) (на английском)

Comment: Не помогло, но спасибо я знаю куда копать теперь

Comment: @tutankhamun, `hp` у `$1.p` допишите ;)

Comment: @Vitalii посмотрите, не попал-ли запрос в кеш.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, все работает