# Как правильно написать правило в .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Здравствуйте

мой .htaccess сейчас выглядит так:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)$ $1 [R=301,L]

Options -Indexes
Options -Includes
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Задача такая:
Мне нужно еще подключить файл админки который лежит в корне сайта.
Если в адресной строке набрать site.com/dashboard нужно подключать файл dashboard.php вместо index.php

Прошу помощи в реализации.

Comment: Делайте все в роутере index.php, а не в .htaccess. А то понадобится перейти на nginx и опять голову ломать.

Comment: на данном этапе, нужна именно эта реализация

Comment: `RewriteRule ^dashboard$ dashboard.php [QSA,L]` после `RewriteBase /`.

Comment: к сожалению это правило работает только если после dashboard ничего нет. а например если site.com/dashboard/login правило уже не срабатывает.

Comment: Вся проблема в том, что в вопросе ни чего этого не описано. Вот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/684657/186083 в котором реализован доступ к php файлам без наличия `.php` в запросе. Возможно вам подойдет.